# How to expand properties for multiple objects in Powershell and import the output to CSV

Tags: powershell, properties, expand, expandoobject

I am trying to expand the properties for a couple of objects, but every time I try, it wont show the output as expected.

Below is my script, would like to know what am I missing here

```
$app = Get-Brokerapplication |
ForEach {
    new-object psobject -property @{
    Type =$_.ApplicationType;
    AssociatedFullName= ($_|select -Expand 
    AssociatedUserFullNames).AssociatedUserFullNames
}} 
$app | ft
```

Output:

Type AssociatedFullName

```
                                                                            ---- ------------------                                                                  
                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop                                                       

                                                                 HostedOnDesktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Using member access `.` expands the property. You're trying to expand the same property twice, which results in an empty value.

```
$app = Get-BrokerApplication |
         ForEach-Object {
             New-Object -TypeName 'PSObject' -Property @{
               Type = $_.ApplicationType
               AssociatedFullName = $_.AssociatedUserFullNames
             }
         }
$app | Format-Table
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the AssociatedUserFullNames object has list of users separted by comma and in Parenthesis and I want that list to be mapped to each Object of 'Type'

Comment: @Chandra9787 Please include a sample of what you're describing along with the object type (`.GetType().FullName`)